# ValidationMessage does not change color of a border of Text Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I run into a slight problem recently. While creating a new student, I have to test whether `StudentNo` is already in use, it has to be unique. The testing is in a controller. When `StudentNo` is already in database, I add a custom error:

```
Student studentToCheck = dbContext.Students
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.StudentNo == student.StudentNo);
if (studentToCheck != null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("StudentNumberError",
                    "This Student No. is already in use");
}
```

While it works fine, it doesn't set a border of `TextBox` even though I set CSS style:

```
.field-validation-error
{
    color: Red;
}
.input-validation-error
{
    border-color: Red;
}
```

I have inspected the HTML of resulted website and it looks like I have to add the class `input-validation-error` but I don't know how.

Part of View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentNo)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentNo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentNo)
    @Html.ValidationMessage("StudentNumberError")
</div>
```

and part of class definition:

```
[Required, Display(Name = "Student No.")]
[RegularExpression("^(ST[0-9]{4})$",
        ErrorMessage = "Student No. must be of the form: ST0000")]
public string StudentNo { get; set; }
```

---

EDIT:

I tried to add class manually:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("StudentNumberError", new { {"class", "input-validation-error"} } )
```

or

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("StudentNumberError", new Dictionary<string, object>(){ {"class", "input-validation-error"} } )
```

but none of these works :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the error for `RadarNumberError`, but you should be adding it for `StudentNo` if you expect that field to be highlighted:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("StudentNo",
                "This Student No. is already in use");
```

Then on your view you just need to render the errors for `StudentNo`

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentNo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentNo)
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it's supposed to be `StudentNumberError`. Thanks for help. I'll try this ASAP :)

Comment: It's working. OMG I am learning all the time. I though `AddModelError` would work only with custom errors :p